# automatically updated and cached views

Tags: mysql

Assume I want to find ids that appear in both mode=1 and mode=2:

```
SELECT id FROM tab a WHERE mode=1 and (SELECT COUNT(*) from tab b where b.mode=2 and a.id=b.id) = 0
```

and I need this query to run very quickly, even though the table contains millions of rows (already have an index on id1 and on id2). Is there a way to create something like a view that contains this query, that is updated automatically every time the table changes, to have the results prepared for me in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table called summary_tab. Use a programming language or command line to execute a query like this:

```
insert into summary_tab 
select id from ...
```

Then, use a task scheduler like cron to execute the script or command line every few minutes.

The other option is to create an AFTER INSERT trigger on your table that will execute a query like this and update summary table. However, if the query takes a long time and/or if you are inserting a bunch of records in `tab` table, the trigger will slow inserts down.

You could also try something like this:

```
select id
from tab
where mode in (1, 2)
group by id
having count(*) = 2
```

Check the speed and results of this query. If it is not that fast, try creating an index on id and another index on mode and yet another with combination of id+mode and see if one of the indexes makes the query fast enough that you don't have to use a summary table.